# intersection closure for boolean functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This seems a basic thing yet I'm having hard time understanding it. Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ be a set of $n$ elements and $S$ be a  set of boolean functions from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$. So every element in $S$ is an element of $\{0,1\}^n$.

I am trying to check whether $S$ is closed under intersection. I know how to do it for power set But If we stick with $S$ as subset of $\{0,1\}^n$, how could we check the closure property? For example, what's the element $s\cap s'\in S$ i'm looking for if $s=\{1,1,1,0,1,0\}$ and $s'=\{0,1,0,0,1,0\}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically in elementary set theory, functions are defined as collections of ordered pairs.  So let's take a simple example for when $X = \{ 1,2,3 \}$.  Let's say $s(1) = 0$, $s(2) = 1$, and $s(3) = 1$.  Then our function would be $s = \{ ( 1,0) , (2,1) , (3,1) \}$.

So thinking like this, $S$ won't be closed under intersection.  Because the elements between $s$ and $s'$ will be the values in common.  That is, let's say $s'(1) = 1$, $s'(2) = 0$, and $s'(3) = 1$.  Then $s' = \{ (1,1) , (2,0) , (3,1) \}$ and the intersection $s \cap s' = \{ (3,1) \}$ which is not in $\{ 0,1 \}^X$.